# How to solve opencv error " VIDIOC_S_FMT error 16, Device or resource busy "

Tags: ubuntu, opencv, usb, webcam

I am using opencv 2.1 on ubuntu 11.10. When i tried to run a sample program to manipulate video from two usb web cameras an error shown as below

I tried the statement `$ v4l2stereo -0 /dev/video0 -1 /dev/video1`

Got an error like this

```
hue is not supported
hueauto is not supported
VIDIOC_S_FMT error 16, Device or resource busy
```

When i changed the command like this `$ v4l2stereo -0 /dev/video1 -1 /dev/video0`
I got an error like

```
hue is not supported
hueauto is not supported
hue is not supported
hueauto is not supported
(Left image:2388): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",
(Left image:2388): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",
(Left image:2388): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",
(Left image:2388): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",
Failed to acquire images
```

Kindly Help me 
Thank You

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Installing gtk2-engines-pixbuf should do the trick for the video problem:

```
$ sudo apt-get install gtk2-engines-pixbuf
```

Answer (score 0):

If the camera worked fine before, but later started showing this error then make sure you didn't modify by chance the video memory allocation. To double-check run `sudo raspi-config` and under **Advanced Options** > **Memory Split** ensure you allocated at least 128MB.